# Ajax request not fired in django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

i have a problem, i think the ajax doesn't reach the matched view. This is the ajax I'm trying to send

```
$.ajax(
                {
                    url : 'ajax/create_lobby/',
                    data: {
                        'creator' : data.message.creator,
                        'opponent' : data.message.opponent,
                    },
                    headers:{
                        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data){
                        alert("Sended ajax request");
                    }
                }
            )
```

where  `var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();`

The main urls.py contains this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('chat/', include('chat.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #this is what is not working
re_path(r'^ajax/create_lobby/$', quizViews.createLobby, name = "create_lobby"),
    path("lobbies/", include('lobbies.urls')),
    path("lobby/", include('quiz.urls')),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

So i took care of matching urls more restrictive first.

This is the matched view by the url:

```
@csrf_exempt
def createLobby(request):
    creator = request.GET.get("creator", None)
    opponent = request.GET.get("opponent", None)
    print(creator)
    print(opponent)
    data = {
        'creator' : creator,
        'opponent' : opponent
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

This is the info i get in pycharm's console:

```
HTTP GET /lobbies/ajax/create_lobby/?creator=mihai&opponent=alexandru 200 [0.09, 127.0.0.1:56867]
```

If i try to send via POST method i get in console the next message but i don't understand why.

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /lobbies/ajax/create_lobby/
```

The ajax seems to not be fired and i can't see the problem. Can you help me, i'm new to ajax. Thank you!

Comment: did you pass data to JsonResponse?

Comment: I edited. Now i send data but nothing happens.

Comment: What does the browser console say.... Did you check? Do you actually want to send via ```GET``` method?

Comment: The browser's console doesn't display any message. I tried with POST method but i get the forbidden error in pycharm's console.

Comment: Do you want to use get or post exactly?

Comment: I would like to use POST as I  want to make changes on data server.

Comment: Can you check my answer and let me know if it worked... It should work with a ```POST``` method !!! Also, ```print(opponent)``` Does this show up in console?